# explicitly setting the interval for distributed GCs does not seem to work

Tags: java, garbage-collection, rmi, frequency

I have been trying to control the interval between Full GCs triggered by RMI when using JMX (known as *distributed* GCs). Specifically, I start my java platform like this:

```
java -javaagent:../lib/licenceagent.jar=../etc/licence.lic,../etc/publicKeys.store -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:HeapDumpPath=../logs -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:../logs/gc.log -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8004 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=7200000 -cp ../lib/myjar.jar:../etc:../data com.acme.myExecutable
```

As you can see, I set the server GC interval to 2 hours (the value is in millis). As a consequence, and according to what I have seen online, I should expect the Full GC (System) to happen every two hours. Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case, and while inspecting the GC log file I observe a Full GC (System) exactly each hour, which is the default interval for this type of GCs.

Funny enough, if I set the server GC interval to values smaller then an hour, for instance I have tried 30000 that gives me a GC every 30 secs, I can see Full GCs every 30 secs.

So it seems overriding the default interval with values below an hour will work, while trying to get the FGCs less frequently than an hour does not work. That contradicts what I have seen online, here people seems to be able to control the frequency through this option.

I have tried a few things, for instance try to alternate startup options in case of conflicts, or even changing their order in case order of parameters is important in startup scripts (not that I know this is true), but nothing. Was wondering if anyone has experienced the same issue, or can recommend a way forward to ensure this works?

My tests are on a CentOS 64bit machine:

> [root@machine]# java -version
>
> java version "1.6.0_37"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: The system property you are setting concerns local GC, not distributed GC. The distributed GC intervals are controlled via system properties set at the client. It isn't clear from the disagreement between your title and your question which of these you are really trying to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my way out of this problem. The reason why `server.gcInterval` was not working is that the scrips needed the client-side coutnerpart `client.gcInterval` to be defined in order to work.

I have not seen this dependency mentioned anywhere within Oracle docs or over the web, and the only way I had to realise this was trying.

Comment: I found this to be true also on Java 1.7 (1.7.0_80)